# variable sized inputs of different types

Tags: scala

I have a bunch of objects of type `SomeType[T]`. Like some of them are `SomeType[String]`, some are `SomeType[Int]`, etc. I want to write a function which gets a variable-sized set of these (but, potentially of different types).

If I know that the types are all the same I could use something like the following:

```
def someFun[T](inputs: SomeType[T]*): = { 
   // do something here on the list of inputs. 
}
```

Any ideas how to make it generic so that it gets list of inputs with potentially different types? (e.g. `inputs: SomeType[String]` and `inputs: SomeType[Int]`) 
BTW, I don't want to use `SomeType[_]` since I need the type information later on.

Comment: What type does this method return? You could use a wild card `SomeType[_]`, but you'd lose type information.. so the answer really depends on what the body of that method requires. What you're essentially looking for is a K-list.

Comment: Good point. I cannot do `_` since I need the type information later on :-/

Comment: Take a look at Shapeless' [HList](https://github.com/milessabin/shapeless/wiki/Feature-overview:-shapeless-2.0.0#heterogenous-lists).

Comment: I think the short answer is that with repeated parameters this simply is not possible, but with something like a `shapeless.HList` you can achieve something similar.

Comment: What exactly do you mean when you say "I cannot do _ since I need the type information later on"? _Which_ type information do you need? Remember, that they are all different, and that type parameters are erased at runtime. Imagine that what you are trying to do was possible, and post some sample code showing how exactly you would use these arguments. 
And no, HList won't help with this either: you need to know all types upfront to work with it, it's a different use case.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure what you need the type information for but if all you have to do is to react to input directly (without, say, passing it to another function etc), then the following would work:

```
case class Box[A](a: A)

def someFun(boxes: Box[_]*) = 
  boxes.foreach {
    case Box(a: Int) => println(s"INT: $a")
    case Box(a: String) => println(s"STRING: $a")
    case _ => // and so on ...
  }
```

And AFAIK, shapeless's `HList` doesn't solve this as for it to work, you still need to have types upfront.

Comment: Very good suggestion. But the issue is that I don't know the possible types a priori. But I can ask the client pass them somehow. Is it that possible to variable-sized type tags as well?